# Is there a Mac application that lets you manage google docs from the desktop?

Tags: macos, mac, google-docs

On my iPhone there is a program called notemaster that lets me manage Google Docs right from my phone. But I was wondering if there is a similar app for the Mac?

Comment: Safari, Firefox, Opera, Chrome

Answer (score 5):

Cyberduck recently added support for Google Docs http://cyberduck.ch/

Comment: The free and open-source option always deserves recognition.  Cyberduck will let you open the Google document in an editor of your choice (I used OpenOffice), and will update the file on the Google Docs server when you save the file in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Google Drive files through WebDAV using OS X’s built-in WebDAV capabilities.
Just use an online service (I use http://synqya.appspot.com) for WebDAV access, then use the “Connect to Server…” option from the “Go” menu in the Finder, enter connection details and once you have an authenticated server connection, it will mount a network drive on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old....

But since this question was first asked, docs has been rejiggered, and Google released [Google Drive](http://www.google.com/drive) for most platforms.