# Is there a way to mount Google Docs like a drive on the Mac?

Tags: macos, google-docs

I know that I can access Google Docs from Cyberduck and add/change docs.

But is there a way to mount Google Docs so I can access it like a drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Mac application that lets you manage google docs from the desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/105400/is-there-a-mac-application-that-lets-you-manage-google-docs-from-the-desktop)

Comment: @espertus don't know how I missed your comment. Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with [google-docs-fs](http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/) in concert with  [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).

For more information, refer to the [Online Manual for google-docs-fs](http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/wiki/OnlineManual) which lists all the prerequisites needed for installation and has installation instructions for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 6):

You can install Google's [Google Drive app](https://www.google.com/drive/download/)

This is also available on [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install --cask google-drive
```

Answer (score 4):

Google Docs was rebranded Google Drive and a local folder can be created that will have its contents uploaded/on-sync.

As Lake pointed on the comments, while this is not exactly "mounting as Mac OS Drive" it may help.

The software you need can be downloaded from http://drive.google.com/

Comment: It should be noted that the OSX Finder/etc treats Folders and Drives differently in a variety of ways. So while this may suit the original asker of the question it is technically not "Mounting Google Docs (aka Google Drive) as a Mac OS Drive".

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can access your Google Drive files through WebDAV using OS X’s built-in WebDAV capabilities.
Just use an online service (I prefer http://synqya.appspot.com) for WebDAV access, then  you need to use the “Connect to Server…” option from the “Go” menu in the Finder, enter connection details and once you have an authenticated server connection, it will mount a network drive on your desktop.